# Как правильно создать Unit-тест для IHttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, юнит-тесты

я использую XUnit и Moq.
есть следующий код

```
public class RtbService : IRtbService
{
  private readonly HttpClient _client;
  private readonly ILogger<RtbService> _logger;

  SelectingСounter selectingСounter = new SelectingСounter();

  public RtbService(IHttpClientFactory client, ILogger<RtbService> logger)
  {
     _client = client.CreateClient();
     _logger = logger;
  }

public async Task<AuctionRequest?> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, string protocol, int Identification)
  {
   // Код метода
  }
}
```

Необходимо протестировать метод `ProcessBidRequest()` но для этого надо передать в качестве параметров Moq объекты `IHttpClientFactory` и `ILogger` и если с `ILogger` более менее понятно, то как создать Moq объект для `IHttpClientFactory`?

В интернете находил такое решение - https://anthonygiretti.com/2018/09/06/how-to-unit-test-a-class-that-consumes-an-httpclient-with-ihttpclientfactory-in-asp-net-core/ но мне оно не подошло

Comment: Статья правильная, чем этот метод не устроил?

Comment: Метод `ProcessBidRequest` использует внутри себя `_client`? Если нет, то и мокать нечего.

Comment: Да, `ProcessBidRequest` использует `_client` внутри  себя

Comment: `но мне оно не подошло` ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1306588/213987